# R: Identify Duplicates in a column according to condition in the same column

Tags: r, duplicates

I need to identify duplicates in a dataframe in a specific column.
However, I do not want to eliminate all the duplicate values, but just those showing "http" as initial part of the string in that column.

Normally I would identify the duplicates with the line of code below:

```
Dup <-data[(duplicated(data[c("var1")])),]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try `data[grepl("^http", data$var1) & duplicated(data$var1),]`.  If you want to eliminate the duplicates, just negate it. `data[!(grepl("^http", data$var1) & duplicated(data$var1)),]`

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need another condition with `grep` to make sure that only those strings that begin with "http" and is a duplicate will be removed from the dataset.

```
data[!(grepl("^http", data$var1) & duplicated(data$var1)),]
```